# as: unrecognized option '-EL' while compiling android kernel on ubuntu 14

Tags: android, linux, gcc, makefile

```
ARCH=arm64
SUBARCH=arm64
CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-
```

Following is the output of make

```
# make
CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
as: unrecognized option '-EL'
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2    
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
```

still the "as" is used from `binutils (/usr/bin/as)` instead of `/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-android-as`
despite of gcc versions, `gcc-4.4 gcc-4.6 gcc-4.8`, Ubuntu always install same `binutils`

renaming `/usr/bin/as` does not help & make fails

how can I make "make" use right "as" while cross compile.

Comment: Did you try defining "as" during configure. i.e. "export AS=aarch64-linux-android-as" or "AS=aarch64-linux-android-as ... ./configure ?

Comment: I did try export AS=aarch64-linux-android-as & it gave me same output as earlier. Since this is a cross compile, I'm not sure if a global export of AS=aarch64-linux-android-as is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Put `make clean` over the kernel. Then compile the problem fixed.

Comment: Could you rephrase that; it's not entirely clear what you mean

Comment: In the Android package inside the kernal_imx put make clean.

Comment: It's a bit late, but that doesn't actually address the issue.